# AlertDialog in onCreate

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, oncreate

I create an ***AlertDialog*** in ***onCreate*** method. I want it to display only in the first launch of the class. But the problem is that it displays when i change the orientation of the device.
I can't use ***android:configChanges*** because of the architecture of the application.
Is there any other solution to not to display ***AlertDialog*** when I change the orientation?
Thank you.

Here is how i create my ***AlertDialog*** on ***onCreate***

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.module);
    new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this).setTitle("Activity")
        .setMessage("Alert?")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                // do something
            }
         })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                // do nothing
            }
         })
         .show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Comment: Is this first time of use on the app ever or just only once every time you launch the app?

Comment: every time I launch the app

Comment: i think you should use static variable or SharedPreference to store value like `boolean` to check whether your Dialog is already displayed or not..in onCreate() check for this variable and display according to that

Comment: Can you call this activity from different places? if not you may want to use a var to store if the dialog has been shown and keep that var using onSaveInstance method.

Comment: @zozelfelfo yes i can it from different places.

Answer (score 0):

Just Add this `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in your manifest file where you declared your `MyActivity`